# CentOS 6 Yum update issue

Tags: linux, centos, yum, update

I get this error when I try and run 'yum-complete-transaction' in shell:

```
[root@namesvr ~]# yum-complete-transaction
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
There are 1 outstanding transactions to complete. Finishing the most recent one
The remaining transaction had 35 elements left to run
Package 1:httpd-tools-2.2.15-31.el6.centos.vm.x86_64 already installed and latest        version
Package 2:mod_ssl-2.2.15-31.el6.centos.vm.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package wbm-virtual-server-4.09.gpl-1.noarch already installed and latest version
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP.x86_64 0:1.4.8-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package GeoIP.x86_64 0:1.5.1-5.el6 will be an update
---> Package ca-certificates.noarch 0:2013.1.95-65.1.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package ca-certificates.noarch 0:2014.1.98-65.0.el6_5 will be an update
---> Package e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6 will be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6_5.1 will be an update
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6 will be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6_5.1 will be an update
---> Package grub.x86_64 1:0.97-83.el6 will be updated
---> Package grub.x86_64 1:0.97-84.el6_5 will be an update
---> Package httpd.x86_64 1:2.2.15-29.el6.vm.1 will be updated
---> Package httpd.x86_64 1:2.2.15-31.el6.centos.vm will be an update
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:9.03.40-2.el6.centos.1 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: postgresql-8.4.20-1.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: postgresql-8.4.20-1.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 8.83-1 for package: plymouth-0.8.3-27.el6.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 6.75 for package: 12:dhclient-4.1.1-38.P1.el6.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-49.el6_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: 1:dovecot-2.0.9-7.el6_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: 1:dovecot-2.0.9-7.el6_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: 1:dovecot-2.0.9-7.el6_5.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: 1:quota-3.17-21.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 6.38 for package: 1:quota-3.17-21.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 8.36 for package: 1:httpd-2.2.15-31.el6.centos.vm.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 8.63-1 for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 5.20 for package: openssh-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
-> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: postgresql-server-8.4.20-1.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: postgresql-server-8.4.20-1.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 8.11.1-1 for package: kernel-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts >= 5.86-1 for package: kbd-1.15-11.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: initscripts for package: cloud-init-0.7.4-2.el6.noarch
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-431.el6 will be erased
--> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-431.23.3.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-431.20.3.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-431.23.3.el6 will be an update
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-431.20.3.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-431.23.3.el6 will be an update
---> Package libcom_err.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6 will be erased
---> Package libcom_err-devel.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6 will be updated
---> Package libcom_err-devel.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6_5.1 will be an update
---> Package libss.x86_64 0:1.41.12-18.el6 will be erased
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 2:2.2.15-29.el6.vm.1 will be erased
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.10.2-1.el6_5 will be erased
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.15.3-6.el6_5 will be erased
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.15.3-6.el6_5 will be erased
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.15.3-6.el6_5 will be updated
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.16.1-4.el6_5 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kernel-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: dracut-kernel >= 002-18.git413bcf78
       Removing: dracut-kernel-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch (@updates)
           dracut-kernel = 004-336.el6_5.2
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-335.el6.noarch (base)
           dracut-kernel = 004-335.el6
       Available: dracut-kernel-004-336.el6.noarch (updates)
           dracut-kernel = 004-336.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 19 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
audit-2.2-4.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-2.2-2.el6.x86_64
audit-libs-2.2-4.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-libs-2.2-2.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.1.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.12-    1.132.el6_5.1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-devel-2.12-    1.132.el6_5.1.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-headers = ('0', '2.12', '1.132.el6_5.2')
gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with gnutls-2.8.5-13.el6_5.x86_64
1:httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.vm.1.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-tools = ('1', '2.2.15', '29.el6.vm.1')
libcom_err-1.41.12-18.el6_5.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.41.12-18.el6.x86_64
libcurl-7.19.7-37.el6_5.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcurl-7.19.7-37.el6_4.x86_64
libss-1.41.12-18.el6_5.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libss-1.41.12-18.el6.x86_64
libtasn1-2.3-6.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with libtasn1-2.3-3.el6_2.1.x86_64
2:mod_ssl-2.2.15-31.el6.centos.vm.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2:mod_ssl-2.2.15-29.el6.vm.1.x86_64
2:mod_ssl-2.2.15-31.el6.centos.vm.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd = ('1', '2.2.15', '31.el6.centos.vm')
nspr-4.10.6-1.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with nspr-4.10.2-1.el6_5.x86_64
nss-3.16.1-4.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-3.15.3-6.el6_5.x86_64
nss-sysinit-3.16.1-4.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-sysinit-3.15.3-6.el6_5.x86_64
nss-util-3.16.1-1.el6_5.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-util-3.15.3-1.el6_5.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.x86_64 is a duplicate with openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64
```

Doing a 'package-cleanup --problems' results in a similar problem. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved such problems in the past with [package-cleanup](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumUtils) tool (install "yum-utils") with --cleandupes and then repeat `yum check` and `yum-complete-transaction`.

Comment: I get an error when I try and run package-cleanup -cleanupes

Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 18 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:

Comment: It looks like you have a serious RPM breakage and need to be extremely careful if you don't understand how RPM works (which is OK). First, you can add --skip-broken like it's suggested to it fixes what else it can. Then run `yum check` and take a note of which packages are conflicting. Now comes the critical part: download the latest versions of those packages (the ones that yum was supposed to upgrade) and run `rpm --force -Uvh *.rpm` on them so rpm forcibly install them. Run `yum check` again and package-cleanup .

Comment: Still not working.. will not let me install individual rpms.

[root@namesvr tmp]# rpm --force -Uvh glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.1 is needed by (installed) glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.1.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it by running 'package-cleanup --cleandupes' several times and then running yum update. All working okay now. Cheers